# Conditional svg rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm working in React and have an object that looks something like this:

```
[{ 
"title": "instagram", 
"href": "http://instagram.com"
"class": "instagram"
},
{ 
"title": "facebook", 
"href": "http://facebook.com"
"class": "facebook"
},
{ 
"title": "twitter", 
"href": "http://twitter.com",
"class": "twitter"
},
{ 
"title": "twitch", 
"href": "http://twitch.com"
"class": "twitch"
}]
```

and some variables that have an svg path like this...

```
const facebook = <svg path goes here>
const instagram = <svg path goes here>
```

and so on. My idea was to iterate through the object with the map method, and since the name of the classes is the same of the variables, that the variables content replaced the path and the icon showed, something like this:

```
 <div>
            {array.map((item, i) =>{
        
                return <div>
                    <svg  width='40' height='40' viewBox="0 0 38.89 38.91"><path class="cls-1" d={item.class} transform="translate(-24 92.04)"/></svg>
                    </div>
            })
            }
        </div>
```

but the icons aren't showing up. Why isn't the svg appearing? What would be a better solution?

Comment: The `d` attribute defines a path to be drawn. You are just assigning a string like `"instagram"` to it and expecting it to draw the instagram icon.

Comment: How can I assign the path instead of the string?

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

The `d` attribute defines a path to be drawn.

In your example, you are just assigning a string like "instagram" to the path's `d` attribute and expecting it to draw the instagram icon.

This won't work because `d="instagram"` is not a valid svg path command.

If you can edit your data source, why not just add the path there - under the path key in each item in the array?

```
[
    { 
        "title": "instagram", 
        "href": "http://instagram.com"
        "class": "instagram",
        "path": "<svg path goes here>"
    },
    ...
]
```

---

```
<div>
    {array.map((item, i) => {
        return (<div>
            <svg  width='40' height='40' viewBox="0 0 38.89 38.91">
                <path class="cls-1" d={ item.path } transform="translate(-24 92.04)"/>
            </svg>
        </div>)
    })}
</div>
```